# Infinite loading loop Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot

This is my third day on Linux Ubuntu and so far it has been a different expirence but a good one.Anyways, I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my computer and I am having a problem getting to the login screen.When ever I boot up on Linux ubuntu I am stuck on a never ending Ubuntu loading screen before I can login.does anybody know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the choice to boot into recover mode, take that choice, you could try to get to
a none gui login screen and try to start the X server from command line if that doens't work
/var/log/ will be your friend :D access the logs from recover mode, or if you dont get to the recover mode, any live CD will do the job.

Or if you just installed Ubuntu try to reinstall it.

Because without more information like Logs its hard to say where the mistake could 
be.